# Assign value if a specific words precedes different word in a new column

Tags: python

Add a new column when the below conditions are achieved.

1. if "Action" comes before "Scence"  ==> Assign value equal 1 (in a
   new column)
2. if "Dialogue" comes before "Scence" ==> Assign value equal 2 (in a new column)
3. if "Scence" comes before "Scence"  ==> Assign value equal 3 (in a new column)

[image]

My code is as below:

```
for i in range(len(df)):
    if df['Type'][i] == "Action" < df['Type'][i] == "Scene":
        i.append(1)
```

Comment: you are iterating through each row of the df and comparing if the *same* row's 'Type' value is equal to 'Action' or 'Scene', and then you're taking the resulting bool value and seeing if it's less than the other. That isn't what you want to do. You want to check if consecutive rows are equal to 'Action' or 'Scene'

Comment: How to add a column and assign the value of 1 if 'Action' precedes 'Scene'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to assume you're using pandas. Normally you don't want to iterate over each row like the way you're doing. What you can do is create an intermediary column which is just all the values shifted up by 1

e.g. df['shifted_Type'] = df['Type'].shift(-1)

```
import pandas as pd

def foo(row):
  if row['type'] == 'action' and row['shifted_type'] == 'scene':
    return 1
  else: # add other comparisons here
    return 0


df = pd.DataFrame()
# setting up a sample df
df['type'] = ['scene', 'action', 'action', 'scene','action']
# creating new column of 'type' shifted backward by 1
df['shifted_type'] = df['type'].shift(-1)
# creating new column of result with the specified logic in foo applied
df['result'] = df.apply(foo, axis=2)
print(df)
```

OUTPUT:

```
     type shifted_type  result
0   scene       action       0
1  action       action       0
2  action        scene       1
3   scene       action       0
4  action          NaN       0
```

Comment: Thanks for your great effort! 
But I don't want to shift type.

Comment: the shifted_type is just an intermediary step, result is the final column you want

Comment: Thanks for your great effort.

Yes, I am using pandas but I don't want to shift type.

I am classifying my scenes into 3 categories: So if the word "Action" comes before "Scene" this type is labeled as 0 in a new column. And if the word "Dialogue" comes before "Scene" this type is labeled as 1 in the same new column.

Comment: I'm confused as to why you don't want to shift the type, it's just an additional column. You can remove it afterwards e.g. df = df[['type','result']]. You just need to update the foo function with the behavior you're describing

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, @ajoseps your above code is working
I made small amendments only as below:

```
def foo(df):
    if df['Type'] == 'Action' and df['shifted_type'] == 'Scene':
        return 1
    
    elif df['Type'] == 'Dialogue' and df['shifted_type'] == 'Scene':
        return 2
                
    elif df['Type'] == 'Scene' and df['shifted_type'] == 'Scene':
        return 3
    else:
        return 0
df['shifted_type'] = df['Type'].shift(-1)
df['result'] = df.apply(foo, axis=1)
df['result'] = df.apply(foo, axis=1)
pd.options.display.max_rows = None
df
```